# Why did a “related post” link get edited into my answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

[This answer](//academia.stackexchange.com/a/89722/24098) got edited to have a link to a related question at the top. I have since rolled it back.

The question is sort of related, but not the same situation. I don’t see how the link adds anything to this answer. Even if it did, it seems like such an edit isn’t legitimate, because it’s not clearly in line with my intent.

The owner of the edit is the Community user. Looking into this, that’s because [it was proposed by an anonymous user](//academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/49670).

Is this a legitimate edit?

Answer (score 6):

If you ask me, it clearly isn’t; the suggested edit should have been rejected.

Even if the link were related to your answer, you should decide whether this link really reflects your intentions. I only consider others adding links to a post appropriate when it is for providing prerequisite information (e.g., linking to the Wikipedia article for some not commonly known term) or when the author asked for it (“I know we had a question about this recently, but I cannot find it right now”). In cases such as yours where this doesn’t apply, the link can be mentioned in a comment and you can decide whether you want to include it or not.

However, the linked post does not seem to be related to your answer (in particular not more than the question) and therefore this edit should have been a comment on the question, if anything.